# How to open folder without using mouse in Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm recently switched to Mac from Windows. It was quite a pain but I am now adjusted to the Mac commands and shortcuts, except one. That is whenever I select a folder and press <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> it executes the rename. While I was expecting it to open it?

Is there any way I can change the shortcut?

Comment: It's really strange  :)

Comment: You should get used to the enter to rename shortcut because that is how most mac apps will work.  For instance renaming a project in final cut pro you select it and hit enter.  So it isn't just in the finder.  This one annoyed me too when I switched from windows, but you get used to it soon enough.  Also CMD-L for going to the address bar of the browser is another one I had to get used to.  But cmd-tab and cmd-` work great.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To open it, you can use either of these two keyboard shortcuts:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the standard shortcut for opening files)
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: is there a way to change the shortcut key ?

Comment: System Preferences app -> Keyboard, choose "keyboard shortcuts" tab. Click the + sign to add a custom shortcut. You can specify that it's only for Finder.... but you can't assign enter as the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I found one moer shortcut :) command + down arrow

Comment: Also, ⌘↑ will open the enclosing folder, like Backspace on Windows. Holding down the ⌥ (Option) key will also close the current window.

Comment: Well I use "Command + Down Arrow" for opening a folder, and "Command + \" for going back. I did this by adding a custom shortcut in Applications Shortcut -> For Finder and added "Enclosing Folder"  -> "Command + \ "

Comment: update as of Jan 2021: ⌘ ↓

Comment: @izy Can you be more specific – are you referring to MacOS 11 (aka Big Sur)?

Comment: @DougHarris yes the current version, which is Big Sur

Comment: If you are prompted to select a directory by a program, for example when your IDE asks you which directory you want to set as your workspace, ⌘+↓ will enter into a directory, whereas ⌘+O will submit/return the directory. If you don't have a directory highlighted, ⌘ ↓ will return the current one.

Comment: When choosing a location to save a file using the finder popup, it used to be that CMD-O worked for opening subfolders.  you could start typing the name of the subfolder you want, cmd-o to open it then type some more, cmd-o again until you find where you want to save the file and then hit enter.  Apparently this behaviour changed sometime between Mojave and Big Sur because now both enter and cmd-o save the file rather than navigating into a sub directory in the file-save dialog.  When using normal finder window, cmd-o still works to open a directory.  No idea why they changed it. Crap UX.

Comment: ⌘ ↓ - also saves file rather than opening a sub directory in the file-save finder dialog.  So annoying.

Answer (score 58):

I use <kbd>Command</kbd> plus the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys.

Comment: I find this way better than the accepted answer.

Comment: It seems this is more expected behavior.

Answer (score 12):

As well, you can also use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> while Finder is active and type the path of the folder you want to open in the box that appears.   ie:

```
~/Pictures
```

will open your Pictures folder.

Comment: This works great in combination with Finderpath.

Comment: and tab-completion works in the dialog for choosing the path. It's a great combination.

Answer (score 1):

Same situation. But I eased my pain by switching to the "View as Columns" view (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) and navigate to any needed place just using all the arrow keys.

If needed I can again quickly switch to my previous view with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> shortcuts.

This is better (in my case) than staying in "Icons view" and navigating with arrows Up and Down.

Answer (score 0):

Updated combination:
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>↓</kbd>

and as mentioned previously:
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>o</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't try to answer old questions as your first posts, also please expand your answer to fully explain what it does.

Comment: OS version: Big Sur